# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. React JS Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I've had a read at the other answers available for this but can't make sense of it. I'm really not sure where to insert the key in this situation

```
const recursivelyMapChildren = (node, index) => {
return (
    node.children.map((child, i) => {
      if (child.text) return child.text
      const tag = child.tag
      return React.createElement(
        tag,
        {
          key: `${tag}-${index}-${i}`,
          className: `text-block-${tag}`,
          ...child.attributes,
        },
        recursivelyMapChildren(child, index + 1)
      )
    })
  )
}

const STTextBlock = ({ data }) => {
const textTag = data.content[0].tag
  return (
    <div className="text-block">
      {
        data.content.map(textBlock =>
          React.createElement(
            textTag,
            {
              className: `${textTag}`,
            },
            recursivelyMapChildren(textBlock)
          )
        )
      }
      <style jsx>{styles}</style>
    </div>
  )
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how is the `data.content` looks like?

Comment: Why are you mixing `React.createElement` with jsx? Everytime you create elements of equal type in a loop or map call you have to provide a key to make them distinguishable for react. You don't do this in the render method of your `STTextBlock` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a key to the initial array map also see where I have added `UNIQUE_KEY_NEEDED_HERE_ALSO`.

```
const recursivelyMapChildren = (node, index) => {
return (
    node.children.map((child, i) => {
      if (child.text) return child.text
      const tag = child.tag
      return React.createElement(
        tag,
        {
          key: `${tag}-${index}-${i}`,
          className: `text-block-${tag}`,
          ...child.attributes,
        },
        recursivelyMapChildren(child, index + 1)
      )
    })
  )
}

const STTextBlock = ({ data }) => {
const textTag = data.content[0].tag
  return (
    <div className="text-block">
      {
        data.content.map(textBlock =>
          React.createElement(
            textTag,
            {
              key: `UNIQUE_KEY_NEEDED_HERE_ALSO`
              className: `${textTag}`,
            },
            recursivelyMapChildren(textBlock)
          )
        )
      }
      <style jsx>{styles}</style>
    </div>
  )
}
```